# Como ver los permisos que tiene un usuario sobre un fichero en bash

Tags: bash, script, permisos

Estoy haciendo un script que compruebe que si el argumento que nos dan es una ruta absoluta o relativa, la parte que me cuesta sacar es donde dice los permisos que tiene el usuario sobre ese fichero, por que se hacer los permisos que tiene el fichero pero no el usuario sobre el fichero.

Esto es lo que tengo del script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
file=$1
if [[ "$1" = /* ]]; then
        echo "  It´s an absolute path"
else
        echo "  It's a relative path";fi
if [[ -d $1 ]];then
        echo ""
        echo "  $file is a directory";exit 0;fi
```

luego necesito que el script diga que permisos tiene el usuario que ejecuta el script sobre el fichero

```
if [[ $USER tiene permisos para escribir sobre $file ]]; then
        echo ""
        echo "$USER has write premissions"
if [[ $USER tiene permisos para ejecutar $file ]]; then
        echo ""
        echo "$USER has execute premissions"
if [[ $USER tiene permisos para leer $file ]]; then
        echo ""
        echo "$USER has reading premissions"
```

Esto como se haría?

Comment: no me queda clara la duda. Aquí el código hace muchas cosas, ¿cuál no te funciona o te genera dudas?

Comment: El problema es que en vez de comprobar que permisos tiene el usario sobre el fichero, comprueba los permiosos del fichero

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Utiliza `ls -l`, y verás los permisos que tiene algún usuario o grupo sobre el fichero.

Comment: @Cuauhtli es muy indirecto, además, `ls -l` solo muestra los permisos DAC de Unix, mientras que esconde parcialmente las ACLs y contextos de SELinux, que también determinan si un usuario puede (y cómo) acceder a un archivo.

Comment: Tienes razón @D4RIO. Aunque el OP no especificó sobre SELinux. Creerías que la respuesta más adecuada a su caso tenga que ver con usar el built-in `[[` con los flags específicos para cada permiso (r,w,x)?

Comment: Por cierto, @IsaacSanz. Deberías dividir tu publicación en varias. Una preguntando sobre la ruta relativa, otra sobre los permisos; y en cada una añadiendo lo que haz intentado y lo que esperas obtener. Así tus preguntas podrán ayudar a más personas con las mismas dudas.

Comment: Vale la dividiré y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Cuauhtli, puede ser. `[[` y `test` usan el UID efectivo y llaman a eaccess (el builtin usa una función parecida propia de bash) ([builtins](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L533), [test](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/test.c#L414)). No se exactamente si [eaccess o euidaccess](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/euidaccess.3.html) leen las ACLs o toman en cuenta SELinux, pero que leen el DAC de Unix es seguro. Es importante que el permiso que devuelven es el efectivo, no el del usuario que ejecuta.